How to prevent color changes when the text property of TextMeshPro is modified
As you can see, I use a method to modify the text property of TextMeshPro, and immediately after the modification, I change its vertex color (red or white), and then use the ForceMeshUpdate method. However, the text still briefly returns to the default color (green) for a moment. I am currently aware that a series of methods are called when the text property is modified. I am investigating the cause of the problem in the source code. To avoid wasting too much time, I would like to ask if anyone has any ideas about such an issue?
public void ChangeText(string text)
{
    if (m_textMeshPro != null)
    {
        m_textMeshPro.text = text;
        UpdateTime(m_timeTemp); // set vertex color
        m_textMeshPro.ForceMeshUpdate();
    }
}


What if you call UpdateTime(m_timeTemp); at first? So just move it one line above. Does this fix the issue?

I think you should make it a coroutine and wait one frame after the text is set.

@TheQuaX
I've tried it, and it doesn't seem to work. In fact, before I call the ChangeText method, there is a Coroutine that continuously calls the UpdateTime method until I trigger a certain condition, and then calls ChangeText. Everything is normal before the text property is modified, but once the property is changed, the text will be rendered back to the default color (green) for an instant.
After research, I found that the rendering mechanism of UGUI is to insert the content to be rendered into a queue to be rendered, and then render them uniformly in the next frame. When the text property is changed, TMP needs to re-render the text. Obviously, the vertices to be rendered are not the same as the previously rendered vertices, so TMP cannot use the previously set vertex colors to set the new vertices, and thus TMP uses the default color for rendering. However, my research has only reached this point, and I still need to clarify some things: 1. Whether the content to be rendered is inserted into the render queue together with the render data, like a snapshot, and when it's its turn to render, it renders in the state it was in when it was inserted, or does it only insert into the queue, and when it's its turn to render, it renders with the data at the time of rendering. 2. What is the mechanism behind ForceMeshUpdate, how is it supposed to work, and why didn't it work?
In addition, my current solution is to use an extra TMP to modify the text in advance and set it to invisible. When the current TMP needs to modify the text, replace the visual effect of the current TMP with the extra TMP, and then set the current TMP to invisible. Of course, this method will consume more memory and I don't know which is better, ForceMeshUpdate or this solution.
However, I still need other solutions the aforementioned solutions.
Anyway, thank you for your suggestions.

I'm not sure how this relates to the question. When the Text property is updated, there is no colour change, so the original question is incomplete, and your answer seems unrelated. The OP should post more context regarding the code used.
